# Cannot download from terminal with curl -O

Tags: curl, download, wget

I try to download the something-something dataset onto a server with the command line. It is split into multiple parts, the small introduction file is for example downloaded [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/downloads/20bn-something-something-download-instructions?referrer=node/68935):

I tried to download this file with the following command:

`curl -O https://developer.qualcomm.com/downloads/20bn-something-something-download-instructions?referrer=node/68935`,

but the downloaded file is a small, corrupted file. I also tried to download the file with the addition of my username:

`curl -O https://developer.qualcomm.com/downloads/20bn-something-something-download-instructions?referrer=node/68935 -u username:password`,

but the outcome is the same. I also tried `wget`, but it doesn't work either.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *I also tried `wget`, but it doesn't work either* then please add exact command which you have tried. Aside from that: is file you want to download supposed to be public or is there authentication required? If second what kinds are supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to use the Chrome extension `Get cookies.txt` to create a file for the cookies. Then you can use `wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt <address>` and it works fine.